# React TS: Select / Option-Element Warning: select: `key` is not a prop

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I'm facing an issue with a React drop-down element using TypeScript. Whenever I change an item in the drop-down, the following warning appears:

> Warning: option: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. ([Special Props in React](https://reactjs.org/link/special-props))

Here's the code snippet that's causing the problem:

```
typescript
interface IDropDownProps {
  values: string[];
  handler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
}

const DropDown = ({ values, handler }: IDropDownProps) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={handler}>
      {values.map((value, index) => (
        <option key={index}>{value}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

function App() {
  const values = ["1", "2", "3"];

  const valueHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropDown values={values} handler={valueHandler} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I suspect the issue is within the `valueHandler` function, where I'm accessing the "e" event. Interestingly, when I log "e.target.value", no error occurs.

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: created a codesandbox demo out of you code, and it not throwing warning for me. are you trying to access `props.key` anywhere else in your code? Also as a side note, indexes should not be used as keys.

Comment: @RichardZilahi, thank you for your response! :)

I tested the code again on my Mac, and interestingly, no warning occurred. However, I did find this warning on the Mac and was able to recreate the issue on a Windows PC.

Just to clarify, the code I provided encompasses the entire project. I created a new one specifically to isolate and test this issue.

I also checked the Chrome version, and it's the same across both systems. Additionally, I was able to reconstruct the issue on another PC as well.

I have no idea anymore XD